# Run method on first set of UICollectionViewCells, but no on subsequent cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` containing cells that are showing a preview of the camera. I've added a black `UIView` as a "veil" on top of the cell through storyboard.

When the camera previews begin, I animate the veil `UIViews` of all cells from an `veil.alpha = 1` to `veil.alpha = 0`. This smooths out the effect of the camera preview starting.

However, this means that when a cell is initialized, but not added to the view, I have to wait until it's added to the view before I can remove the veil `UIView`. If I attempt beforehand, the veil `UIView` is nil.

The result is that as I'm scrolling, I catch a glimpse of the veil being animated away for any cells that have not been initialized beforehand.

A simple solution would be to check something like:

> "If this cell is being scrolled into visibility, and the camera is already running, before the cell is visible, just set the
>   `veil.alpha = 0`."

However, I'm not sure where in the cell/controller lifecycle to put this.

I've tried setting this in `prepareForReuse()`, `layoutSubviews()` in the cell, and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in containing controller. All three of those methods cause the veils of the initial visible cells to immediately jump to `veil.alpha = 0` without the animation.

Thank you.